# Accessing Google Calendar API with OAuth2 on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build google calendar functionality for an iPhone app. I understand I need to be authorized with OAuth2 and would like help some help. The iPhone app is accessing a public calendar and therefore the user is not supposed to login with a webview like the google toolbox framework. FWIW, I have my account set up. Any framework recommendation or good tutorials for this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat as you. The info you find on this is scarce and confusing... unfortunately.

You've probably already been to [Google's API Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). This [post](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/) helped me to get the GDataObjC-Client to work in my project.

Google's samples are unfortunately all for Mac and not iOS. Their take on it is, that the methods are pretty much the same for iOS as they are for Mac, so you figure it out how you translate the Mac portion to iOS.

I ended up doing just that... I created a new XCode project and brought over the code of CalendarSampleWindowController of the Mac-app to my ViewController.

Good luck!

Comment: I actually ended up using that same post and it eventually worked fine for me. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: thx... i am still working on it... slow, but making progress. ;)

Comment: actually, i posted the following question here yesterday, regarding the [reoccurring permission dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625911/ios-app-using-google-api-oauth2-asking-for-permission-again-and-again). maybe you've some idea how to fix it. cheers

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to handle that -- never needed to use the dialog. The project I worked on just needed access to google calendar, but not the user's. Therefore, never needed the user's credentials. I just used logged in with the credentials I had.